# Generating custom strings from a numerical range and saving it to an array in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I got a string in bash script that looks like this:

```
 nodeParts="node[0-2]\n node[3-5]"
```

(a string seprated by a newline in the middle). What I need to do is to expand these numbers and put it in an array separately. The result of the expansion should be as follows:

```
 node_array[0]=node0
 node_array[1]=node1
 node_array[2]=node2
 node_array[3]=node3
 node_array[4]=node4
 node_array[5]=node5
```

I used awk command to achieve this but the code is neither elegent nor efficient. The code is as follows:

```
 node_array[0]=""
 count=0
 for node in $nodeParts
 do
      #first isolate the 'node' word
      base=$(echo "$node" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="["}{printf("%s\n",$1);}END{}')
      base=$(echo -e "$base" | tr -d '[:space:]')  

      #now use awk twice to isolate the characters between [ and ]      
      numbers=$(echo "$node" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="["}{printf("%s\n",$2);}END{}')
      numbers=$(echo "$numbers" |  awk 'BEGIN{FS="]"}{printf("%s\n",$1);}END{}')

      #now break the isolated [] by - to get the start and end numbers
      begin=$(echo "$numbers" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="-"}{printf("%s\n",$1);}END{}')
      begin=$(echo -e "$begin" | tr -d '[:space:]') #in case there is white space


      end=$(echo "$numbers" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="-"}{printf("%s\n",$2);}END{}')
      end=$(echo -e "$end" | tr -d '[:space:]')

      #use a while loop to add it to the node_array
      while [ $begin -le $end ]
      do
              node_array[$count]="$base$begin"
              ((count++))
              ((begin++))
      done
 done
```

As you can see, it's a very basic implementation. And all I know is awk. I would appreciate if you could help me to improve this code to make it more efficient and smaller.

-ppgoodman.

Comment: The only built-in functionality in the shell for replacing `node[0-2]` with matches like `node0` `node1` `node2` matches against files that actually exist on disk. If you're trying to generate new names that don't correspond with filesystem entries, there's nothing built-in for the purpose.

Comment: Where does the original definition you're trying to transform come from? Can you change how it's defined? `node_array=( node{0,1,2} node{3,4,5} )` would be a one-line literal with the exact effect you want.

Comment: (btw, as an aside -- bash actively violates the POSIX sh standard when it has `echo -e` do anything other than print `-e` on output -- which it doesn't always do, as it can be configured with the `xpg_echo` option to strictly comply. Much better to follow the advice at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section -- and use `printf '%b\n' "$foo"` instead of `echo -e "$foo"`).

Comment: ...getting back to `node[0-2]` and its ilk -- if you look at typical implementations of fnmatch-style pattern matching like [the one from the Python standard library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/fnmatch.py) (chosen as an example for easy readability), you'll see that it's actually compiling the expression into a regex, and then matching the regex against a list of names. Going from a regex to a list of possible strings that match it is... not a widely available facility (or a terminable one, in many cases).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy unfortunately that part is read from a file. And this is the format given in the file. Cannot change.

Comment: Who defined the file format? Your awk script is making assumptions that aren't well-founded about what a fnmatch expression looks like -- `node[1-3]` could be written as `node[123]`, for example, or `node[12-3]`, and would have the same meaning in all three cases. For that matter, `node[[:digit:]]` would be a fnmatch expression equivalent to `node[0-9]` or `node[0123456789]`. Lots of ways to write the same thing, not so easy to cover them all if you're trying to write the expansion logic by hand.

Comment: ...if you had a directory with a file (even an empty one!) for every node that exists, you could use the shell's built-in fnmatch support to match the patterns against that directory. Is something that's an option for you? (It's feasible to match against a different inventory/list format as well, if you aren't restricting yourself to shell).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy your printf suggestion is a good one. I'm trying to make my code as portable as possible. Thank you!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that variable is read from a slurm configuration file. As far as I've seen that's the format they use to name the computing nodes. https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/etc/slurm.conf.example has an example and I'm reading the "NodeName" parameter in the file.

Comment: Huh. SLURM is doing its own thing -- when they write `mcr[0-1151]` in their sample configuration, for example, it's clearly intended to mean a very different thing than what that same string would mean to a shell or other fnmatch-style tool (where square brackets define a character set; `[0-1151]` in shell terms means the same thing as `[015]`, matching either a single character `0`, the single character `1`, or the single character `5`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) mentions there is no POSIX built-ins available to do this straight forward. Because the shell applies pathname expansion to pattern `node[0-2]` and looks for files `node0` to `node2` if present or would retain it as an unexpanded glob if no such files exist. So to solve your use case, they need to be treated as fixed strings and not glob patterns.

With a bit of bash-isms involved you could put together a script as below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r -d '' nodeParts << EOM
node[0-2]
node[3-5]
EOM

mapfile -t tempNodeArray <<<"$nodeParts"

# The part up to here is user's choice on how to pass the input
# The example below uses a way to store the multi line string 
# using a heredoc and later passes that to an array by using
# mapfile 

# Defining a regex to match the 'node[digit1-digit2]' part
regex='node\[([[:digit:]]+)-([[:digit:]]+)\]'

# The final array where the output will be stored
nodeArray=()

# For each of the entry in array, do a regex match to extract
# the numbers
for entry in "${tempNodeArray[@]}"; do
    # Take the captured groups on successful regex match and 
    # make a loop over the numbers
    if [[ $entry =~ $regex ]]; then
        start="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        stop="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        for((i=start; i<=stop; i++)); do
            # Adding to the array prefixing with 'node-'
            nodeArray+=( node"$i" )
        done
    fi
done

# Print the final array to see how its stored, also printf '%s\n' "${nodeArray[@]}"
declare -p nodeArray
```

Comment: Generally, looks good. Glancing at slurm's docs, I'm inferring that `node` should be a `[[:alnum:]]+`-style match group itself, substituted into the resulting values.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks Charles! Will let the OP decide the best on what they need.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I'd change it to a `[[:alnum:]]+` thanks

Comment: @Inian looks good, thanks. I guess I'd have to learn regex more.